# Using a Counter Within a For Loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, counter

How would I properly deploy the `gradecount` counter in this for loop?

It should increment after each grade entered.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfGrades; i++){
    double belowzero = gradeinput.nextDouble();
    int gradecount = 1;
    System.out.println("enter grade number " + gradecount + ":" );
    gradecount++;

    while (belowzero < 0){
        belowzero = gradeinput.nextDouble();
    }
    grades[i] = belowzero;
}
}
```

Comment: you want ``gradecount`` is a user input?

Comment: What is the logic behind your program?

Comment: I want gradecount to keep track of how many grades were needed to be entered. Say they needed to enter 4 grades, I just wanted to add in a gradecount that displayed something like this "enter grade 1 here: " then "enter grade 2 here" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize gradecount outside the for loop.

```
int gradecount = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < numOfGrades; i++){
    double belowzero = gradeinput.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("enter grade number " + gradecount + ":" );
    gradecount++;

    while (belowzero < 0){
        belowzero = gradeinput.nextDouble();
    }
    grades[i] = belowzero;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want gradecount to keep track of how many grades were needed to be entered. Say they needed to enter 4 grades, I just wanted to add in a gradecount that displayed something like this "enter grade 1 here: " then "enter grade 2 here" etc.

You don't need a `gradecount` variable you can use the for index `i` instead.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfGrades; i++){
        double belowzero = gradeinput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter grade number " + (i+1) + ":" );

        while (belowzero < 0){
            belowzero = gradeinput.nextDouble();
        }
        grades[i] = belowzero;
    }
```